# How to deal with off topic questions between the conversation?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

Supposed that I mapped a subject and put all questions / answers in order using "continue conversation" flow.

In middle of that conversation I would like to answer a off-subject topic and back to the conversation.

How can I do this?
Could I store the previous node id and back to it with same action?

Answer (score 1):

Bruno, at present Watson Conversation doesn't provide a way to do this branching off in an elegant way.